# Javascript check and select only one option in quiz game

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to choose only one option from the options list. In Quiz Game have 4 options and if clicked I want to add an 'active' class, but I would also want to check that if some options already have selected so I could remove the classList from it.

```
answersList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const option = e.target;

    console.log(answersList.children);

    if (option.classList.contains('active') || answersList.children.classList.contains('active')) {
        option.classList.remove('active')
    } else {
        option.classList.add('active');
    }
```

I was trying something like at above, but clearly that doesn't work. The options are inside a ul as li elements in html. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide enough of your code so that it qualifies as a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? It's hard to debug your code when parts of it are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Inside of your `ul` elements, add an `<input type="radio">` tag. Radio buttons can only have **one selected at a time** which is what I'm assuming you're looking to do. You can style them as you wish as well.

You can select the active radio button with `input[type="radio"]:checked`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to *iterate* over the children and check the class list of each child individually.

You could make it simple and first see what the clicked option's active-setting is, then clear it from **all** children, and then use the first information to toggle the clicked option:

```js
const answersList = document.querySelector("ul");

answersList.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    const option = e.target;

    const isSet = option.classList.contains('active');
    for (const {classList} of answersList.children) {
        classList.remove('active'); 
    }
    option.classList.toggle('active', !isSet);
});
```

```css
.active::after {
    content: "☑"
}
```

```html
<ul>
   <li>Answer 1
   <li>Answer 2
   <li>Answer 3
   <li>Answer 4
</ul>
```

Comment: This works perfectly. Can you explain for me what does the loop actually do? Why is the classList inside a curly brackets? Also what does the toggle's last parameter do?

Comment: The loop removes the `active` class from all list items. The curly braces are syntax for [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) -- a shortcut to immediately get a property of an object, instead of the object itself. The second argument of toggle is described in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle). Instead of toggling, it forces the class on when the second argument is true, and off otherwise.